# Occasionally, My folders simply don't load correctly, no thumbnails, no location shortcuts

Tags: windows-7

[image]

The screenshot shows the difference between 2 folders. The one on the right is the correctly loaded one, while the one on the left is the one which isn't loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is possible to change explorer settings per directory under MS Windows, you might have changed these settings without noticing it. Open the "Display" settings of your explorer and reset it to "Defaults". Let me know how it goes...

Answer (score 0):

You could try rebuilding the thumbnail cache.

A hacky way to do this is to change the default icon size in windows.

1. Press the windows key
2. Type `Display` and press enter
3. Change the Icon size to 'Medium'
4. Log off and log back on

This forces windows to rebuild your cache.

An easier solution is to download [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) and go to `Cleaner` (first left-hand item menu) and run the cleaner ensuring `Thumbnail Cache` under the `Windows Explorer` list group is checked.

I would also go to `Registry` and fix any registry errors you might have.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem under Window 7 ultimate.

In my case nothing listed above worked. I could only tell that it was related to my user account, since the problem would not happen with another user account

I finally discovered that it was related to a corrupted .wmv file lying on my desktop. the File explorer was devoting all its resources trying to read its properties, exploding the CPU occupation and overheating the processor.

The file in question was undeletable and unmovable to another folder under normal circumstances. I got rid of it by booting in safe mode command line under the 'Administrator' account and deleting  it from there

```
c:\cd /users/myusername/Desktop
del OffendingFile.wmv
```

As a side note, while all this was happening, there was a busy process, 'DllHost' described as 'COM Surrogate' that I had not seen before, and that did disappear after I got rid of that file and rebooted under my user

Also an antivirus scan of the file (with both Avast and Malware Byte), shown no infection. The file would play with Windows Media, but not with another player.